# GAE data store returns no data using Python filtering

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

The db schema file is defined as this in the `db/d.py` file:

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
class D(db.Model):
    did = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    sample_tm = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)
    weekday = db.IntegerProperty(required = False)
```

And there has been a bunch of data inserted into the datastore with this schema, as I can see those from the datastore viewer in app engine.

However, problem occurs when I tried to use python to query the data in the handler python script.

```
from db import d
class WaitTimeQuery(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def post(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'         
        q = d.D.all()
        print q.get()
```

And each time it will just print a `None`. Why those data cannot be fetched this way?

Also I tried to use embedded gql in python, again it returns no results, however when executing:

> select * from D

In the data viewer, the results can be displayed correctly

Comment: use google.appengine.ext.ndb instead of db. Also use D.query().fetch() instead of D.all().get()

Comment: @RemcoHaszing thanks for the reply though it's not working. Returned an empty list

Comment: Do the entities have an ancestor? If so you need to specify one in the query function. `D.query(ancestor=my_ancestor_key).fetch()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First as Remco Haszing said, use `ndb` instead of `db` when writing new applications. When writing legacy applications it's OK to use `db` but you should migrate to `ndb`. ;-)

The `required=False` is also not necessary, this is default. ;-)

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

class D(ndb.Model):
    did = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    sample_tm = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    weekday = ndb.IntegerProperty()
```

Creating an instance and putting it:

```
d = D(did='spam')
d_key = d.put()  # Stores the instance.
```

The `d_key` is the `Key` you can use to get the instance back from the datastore.

When you have the possibility do a lookup instead of a query:

```
d = d_key.get()
assert d.did == 'spam'
```

The problem with global queries (`D.query()`) is that there is no insurance there will be results. See [the docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/) for details.

> NDB writes data in steps:
>
> - In the Commit phase, the underlying Datastore service records the changes.
> - NDB invalidates its caches of the affected entity/entities. Thus, future reads will read from (and cache) the underlying Datastore instead of reading stale values from the cache.
> - Finally, perhaps seconds later, the underlying Datastore applies the change. It makes the change visible to global queries and eventually-consistent reads.

After the change is applied in the datastore you may use a global query:

```
results = D.query().fetch()  # results will be a list with D instances
```